# Javascript add two fields/keys together

Tags: javascript, arrays, calculation

Very much a newbie here with Javascript and in programing in general. I'd appreciate any help or guidance you can provide.

I'm working on a side project to pull data from a rest API and display it in a an html table.  Here is the function

```
function example(){

callApi('URL Here',function(apiObject){

   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(apiObject, null, 4)+"</pre>";
   });

};

function callApi(apiRequest,callback) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        callback(jsonObject);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", apiRequest, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Here is what the JSON output looks like:

```
[
{
    "Start_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496121339796,
    "End_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496122179526,
    "End_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:29:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Start_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:15:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Meter": 350000562,
    "Protocol": "v4",
    "Count": 15,
    "rejected_bad": 0,
    "rejected_duplicates": 0,
    "kWh_Tot_Max": 2100.57,
    "Rev_kWh_Tot_Max": 1243.29
},
{
    "Start_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496120439546,
    "End_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496121279556,
    "End_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:14:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Start_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:00:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Meter": 350000562,
    "Protocol": "v4",
    "Count": 15,
    "rejected_bad": 0,
    "rejected_duplicates": 0,
    "kWh_Tot_Max": 2100.35,
    "Rev_kWh_Tot_Max": 1243.13
},
]
```

What I need help with is how to loop through the output and subtract the "Rev_kWh_Tot_Max" value from the "kWh_Tot_Max" value and put the result into a new "field/key" (not sure the correct terminology) in the array.

Here is what I'm trying to get at:

```
[
{
    "Start_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496121339796,
    "End_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496122179526,
    "End_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:29:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Start_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:15:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Meter": 350000562,
    "Protocol": "v4",
    "Count": 15,
    "rejected_bad": 0,
    "rejected_duplicates": 0,
    "kWh_Tot_Max": 2100.57,
    "Rev_kWh_Tot_Max": 1243.29,
    "Net_kWh": 857.28
},
{
    "Start_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496120439546,
    "End_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496121279556,
    "End_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:14:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Start_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:00:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Meter": 350000562,
    "Protocol": "v4",
    "Count": 15,
    "rejected_bad": 0,
    "rejected_duplicates": 0,
    "kWh_Tot_Max": 2100.35,
    "Rev_kWh_Tot_Max": 1243.13,
    "Net_kWh": 857.22
},
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example)

```js
var data = [{
    "Start_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496121339796,
    "End_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496122179526,
    "End_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:29:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Start_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:15:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Meter": 350000562,
    "Protocol": "v4",
    "Count": 15,
    "rejected_bad": 0,
    "rejected_duplicates": 0,
    "kWh_Tot_Max": 2100.57,
    "Rev_kWh_Tot_Max": 1243.29
  },
  {
    "Start_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496120439546,
    "End_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496121279556,
    "End_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:14:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Start_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:00:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Meter": 350000562,
    "Protocol": "v4",
    "Count": 15,
    "rejected_bad": 0,
    "rejected_duplicates": 0,
    "kWh_Tot_Max": 2100.35,
    "Rev_kWh_Tot_Max": 1243.13
  },
];

var output = data.map(function(d) {
  d.Net_kwh = d.kWh_Tot_Max - d.Rev_kWh_Tot_Max;
  return d;
});

console.log(output);
```

If you're looking to round it off to 2 decimal places as well, use

```
d.Net_kwh = Number((d.kWh_Tot_Max - d.Rev_kWh_Tot_Max).toFixed(2));
```

This uses [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to reduce to 2 decimal places and [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Convert_numeric_strings_to_numbers) to convert it back to a number.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, map is more idiomatic than a for loop in JavaScript and it's nice to avoid mutation where possible.

Comment: Thank you guys! Great help!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the JSON `array` and add an attribute as shown below

```js
var json = [{
    "Start_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496121339796,
    "End_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496122179526,
    "End_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:29:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Start_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:15:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Meter": 350000562,
    "Protocol": "v4",
    "Count": 15,
    "rejected_bad": 0,
    "rejected_duplicates": 0,
    "kWh_Tot_Max": 2100.57,
    "Rev_kWh_Tot_Max": 1243.29,
    "Net_kWh": 857.28
  },
  {
    "Start_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496120439546,
    "End_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms": 1496121279556,
    "End_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:14:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Start_Date": "Tue May 30 2017 15:00:39 GMT+1000 (GMT)",
    "Meter": 350000562,
    "Protocol": "v4",
    "Count": 15,
    "rejected_bad": 0,
    "rejected_duplicates": 0,
    "kWh_Tot_Max": 2100.35,
    "Rev_kWh_Tot_Max": 1243.13,
    "Net_kWh": 857.22
  },
];

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  json[i]["Net_kWh"] = json[i]["kWh_Tot_Max"] - json[i]["Rev_kWh_Tot_Max"];
}

console.log(json)
```